# How can I rearrange this sentence? "Dependo de mi novio

Tags: preposiciones, sintaxis, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

I think this is a correct sentence:

> Dependo de mi novio.

If that's correct, then I'm wondering how I can "rearrange" this sentence using different word order and pronouns.

For example, could I say "Le dependo"? "De le dependo"? Maybe I need to use "lo" or "él" instead of "le"? What about something like "De mi novio le dependo"? Maybe those are all wrong, and maybe those aren't the only possibilities, but I think you see what I mean.

Comment: No, **I depend on him** is: **Dependo de él o de mi novio**. You can't just throw out the preposition and expect to get the same meaning. You need to go look up your base verb. Here: depender de alguien. Depend on someone. You need to use the rae.es

Comment: 1. This is another good answer, I will mark it as the answer if you post it as the answer. Sorry @Diego beat you to the last one.

Comment: 2. It sounds like you are saying that **some** of the examples I provided are incorrect. Are you saying that **all** of the examples I provided are incorrect? Are there other examples of different word order/prepositions that would be correct?

Comment: Nothing you did with the phrasing is accurate. I am trying to tell you that if a verb **takes a preposition** as in depender de,  you can't just throw it out. You can ascertain that by looking at the definition in the RAE: https://dle.rae.es/depender They all say depender de algo. See? :)

Comment: That helps! I can slowly make my way through the articles on RAE, but is there an English version?

Comment: Okay, I figured out your problem. :) You need to realize that some verbs take prepositions and others don't. They don't "take prepositional phrases". And in that example with the word para, you changed the sentence around but that is not a standard thing. It was just a rewrite, which is fine but is a different issue. No, dear, there is no English version of the RAE. Are you kidding? It's an entire institution...What is your native language by the way?

Comment: 1. That's a useful rule for me: "if a verb takes a preposition as in depender de, you can't just throw it out." Is that **always** the case? Are there tricky cases? Maybe I can't **just** throw it out, but are there common cases where I can throw it out by changing something else? 2. Some of my examples did not get rid of the preposition "de." I'm guessing that those are wrong, but it must be for a different reason. 3. Even if all my examples are wrong, I'm still looking for other word order/pronouns that would express the same meaning as my original sentence. Can you think of any?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that *depender* "takes" the preposition *de*, and prepara does not "take" the preposition "para." That makes sense to me. The purpose of this question is to understand how verbs like "depender" work. My native language is English.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was this: "is there an English-language version of the RAE **website**?"

Comment: Like I said, do you realize what the RAE is? It is an official authority on the Spanish language. Why would the website have an English "version"? No country with an official authority on their language (like the French also) have translations of their websites.

Comment: @Lambie - An English translation of part of a language regulator's website, you say? [That](https://www.euskaltzaindia.eus/en/euskaltzaindia) [would](https://ujc.avcr.cz/index.html) [be](https://taalunie.org/informatie/112/taalunie-union-for-the-dutch-language) [absurd](https://www.chdpublication.mhrd.gov.in/english/)! [Unthinkable](https://www.sprakradet.no/Vi-og-vart/Om-oss/English-and-other-languages/)! I could mention the Maori language regulator's website (which is mostly bilingual) or the Yoruba one (which is mostly in English), but that might be cheating.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Why are you addressing me about this? Maori and Yoruba are not the same thing at all. The site of the Real Academia and its related sites are not located in a country like India that has three official languages. And Norwegian is a minor language and that "Council" is not a site that is an official dictionary/language encyclopedia site like the RAE's sites. Does the OED have a translated version? Does the French Academy's site have a translated version?? Does Priberam (Portugal) have an English version? The RAE is not a **regulator** whatever than means.

Comment: @Lambie - From "no country with an official authority on their language has translations of their websites" to "Norwegian and Czech and Euskera don't count." By the way, the RAE is indeed a [language regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_regulators?wprov=sfla1), and for what it is worth,  the largest US dictionary, Merriam-Webster, actually does have sites in [Spanish](https://www.nglish.com/spanish/info/aboutus) and [Arabic](https://arabic.britannicaenglish.com/MyZone/Selection) that are joint projects with the Encyclopedia Britannica.

Comment: Oh, and you must have missed that the Norwegian Language Council *does* have [a dictionary site](https://ordbokene.no/), which *does* have an English version. I get that you don't think that the RAE *should* have foreign-language resources, but why present your own preferences as unavoidable rules?

Comment: @Obie2.0 You can keep this up as much as you like. When I said the RAE, I was mainly referring to the dictionary. And that Wikipedia term regulator is misused. In English, we would refer to a language **authority**.  A dictionary for a language has no reason to have an "English version" of its site.  Having a site in Spanish or Arabic, does not mean your "main site" has a Spanish or Arabic *version*.

Comment: @Lambie - A language regulator is exactly what that Wikipedia article says. A language *authority* is someone who thinks that their opinion on correct English terminology supersedes that of everyone else, including the people who contributed to that Wikipedia article. ;) I would say that it is surprising that you don't see the value in defining words for speakers of other languages, but, well, I have already seen what you think of Spanglish, gender-neutral language, and US variants of Spanish, so I guess linguistic purism is your priority here....

Comment: @Obie2.0  The word regulator is misused., A regulator is an entity that regulates things in a legal or quasi-legal sense. However, an authority is a body or institution that says we know, others don't.  **The RAE is not a regulator**; ***it considers itself an authority on the Spanish language***. And actually, I could go into Wikipedia and change that word regulator to authority. English has no institution, body, organization, dictionary, encyclopedia etc. that is an "authority" on the language, much less a regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente diría;

- Yo dependo de él.
- Yo estoy supeditada a él.

Comment: Thanks @DIego! In English, I could say "I depend on him." but I could also say "On him I depend." (although everyone would look at me like I'm insane). Is there something like that in Spanish, where the "de él" phrase moves somewhere else in the sentence (and maybe is changed or replaced)?

Comment: @capet you can also say "De él dependo", which is not the most natural but perfectly correct.